# Javascript return close value function error

Tags: javascript

I have made a function that should sort and return the value of closest objects.
But i have run into a problem if there is no close objects i get this error from getOtherEntity function.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'obj' of undefined
at getOtherEntity (<anonymous>:24:8)
at getClosestEntity (<anonymous>:29:21)
at <anonymous>:1:1
```

I have tried an if statement and a return but it didn't seem to work anyone have any ideas how i can fix this?

```
function GME() {
  return Game.Objects.MyID();
}

function GOE() {
  var MID = GME();
  var obs = Game.Objects;

  return Object.keys(obs).map(function(d, i) {
   if (obs[d].model == "Camp")
    var dx = obs[d].position.x - MID.position.x,
      dy = obs[d].position.y - MID.position.y,
      result = {
        D: (dx * dx) + (dy + dy),
        obj: obs[d],
        valueOf: function() {
          return this.D
        }
      };
      return result;
  }).sort(function(a, b) {
    return a - b;
  })[0].obj; 
}

function GCE() {
  var MID = GME();
  var OE = GOE();
 if (MID == undefined || OE == undefined) return

  var CE = {
    x: OE.position.x - MID.position.x,
    y: OE.position.y - MID.position.y
  }
  return CE;
}
```

Comment: Your `Object.keys(entities).map` callback doesn't return a value all the time (`result` is undefined if the condition is false), so its first entry (`[0]`) can be undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`map` builds a result array from **all** of the entries of the array you call it on. In your case, when `if (entities[d].fromTick.model == "NeutralCamp")` is false, you're returning `undefined`. So apparently your first entry doesn't match that condition.

If your goal is to only look at those models, use `filter` prior to `map`, so the minimum change would be:

```
function GOE() {
  var MID = GME();
  var obs = Game.Objects;

  return Object.keys(obs)
    .filter(function(d) { return obs[d].model == "Camp"; })
    .map(function(d, i) {
      var object= obs[d];
      var dx = object.position.x - MID.position.x,
        dy = object.position.y - MID.position.y,
        result = {
          D: (dx * dx) + (dy + dy),
          obj: entity,
          valueOf: function() {
            return this.D
          }
        };
      return result;
  }).sort(function(a, b) {
    return a - b;
  })[0].obj; 
}
```

...but there's no need for `valueOf` there now that the array reliably contains objects, just use `a.D` and `b.D`:

```
function GOE() {
  var MID = GME();

  var obs = Game.Objects;
  return Object.keys(obs)
    .filter(function(d) { return obs[d].model == "Camp"; })
    .map(function(d, i) {
      var object = obs[d];
      var dx = object.position.x - MID.position.x,
        dy = object.position.y - MID.position.y,
        result = {
          D: (dx * dx) + (dy + dy),
          obj: object
        };
      return result;
  }).sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.D - b.D;
  })[0].obj; 
}
```

---

You might want to use [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) rather than `Object.keys`, since you seem to want the values of the object's properties, not its keys:

```
function getOtherEntity() {
  var MID = GME();
  var objects = Game.Objects;

  return Object.values(objects)
    .filter(function(obs) { return obs.model == "Camp"; })
    .map(function(obs) {
      var dx = obs.position.x - MID.position.x,
        dy = obs.position.y - MID.position.y,
        result = {
          D: (dx * dx) + (dy + dy),
          obj: obs
        };
      return result;
  }).sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.D - b.D;
  })[0].obj; 
}
```

`Object.values` was first added in ES2017 but is easily polyfilled. (ES2017 also added [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries).)

And finally, as [Kaiido points out in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55216348/javascript-return-close-value-function-error/55216447?noredirect=1#comment97169323_55216447), rather than two passes through the array, we can use a single pass via `reduce`:

```
function getD(pos1, pos2) {
  var dx = pos1.x - pos2.x;
  var dy = pos1.y - pos2.y;
  return (dx * dx) + (dy * dy);
}

function GOE() {
  var MID = GME();
  var objects = Game.Objects;

  return Object.values(objects).reduce(
    function(chosen, object) {
      if (
        object && object.model == "Camp" &&
        (!chosen || getD(chosen, MID) < getD(entity, MID))
      ) {
        chosen = object;
      }
      return chosen;
    },
    undefined
  );
}
```

This also has the advantage of returning `undefined` rather than throwing an error if there are *no* Camp entities in the array.

Comment: `.filter(function(entity) { return entity.fromTick.model === "NeutralCamp"; })` isn't this better ?

Comment: @chiril.sarajiu - If `model` is a string, those do exactly the same thing. Using `==` vs. `===` is a matter of style most of the time. If we were getting into style critiques, I'd have a lot more to say about the question's code... ;-)

Comment: Ofc, I meant just to play it safe :) but yeah, the code can be improved :D

Comment: They may even just want the one with the biggest directly, small optimization maybe, but a `reduce` here in place of the whole filter+map would avoid the creation of two arrays for nothing (this kind of micro-optimization is sometimes very important in a game).

Comment: @Kaiido - Quite true! *Something* about `[0].obj` was bothering me, but I hadn't had my morning tea. :-) Are you going to post an answer with that, or should I edit the above?

Comment: @Kaiido - Done. :-)

Answer (score -1):

You need to check if `[0]` of the array exists.

```js
return Object.keys(entities).map(function(d, i) {
   if (entities[d].fromTick.model == "NeutralCamp")
    var dx = entities[d].fromTick.position.x - MyPlayerEntity.position.x,
      dy = entities[d].fromTick.position.y - MyPlayerEntity.position.y,
      result = {
        D: (dx * dx) + (dy + dy),
        obj: entities[d],
        valueOf: function() {
          return this.D
        }
      };
      return result;
  }).sort(function(a, b) {
    return a - b;
  })[0] || {}).obj
```

Answer (score -1):

Update code with below:

```
  var newObj = Object.keys(entities).map(function(d, i) {
    if (entities[d].fromTick.model == "NeutralCamp")
    var dx = entities[d].fromTick.position.x - MyPlayerEntity.position.x,
    dy = entities[d].fromTick.position.y - MyPlayerEntity.position.y,
        result = {
            D: (dx * dx) + (dy + dy),
            obj: entities[d],
            valueOf: function() {
                return this.D
            }
        };
        return result;
}).sort(function(a, b) {
    return a - b;
})[0]; 

if(newObj != undefined){
    return newObj.obj;
}
else{
    return {};
}
```